# Navigation menu fragment import media player

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I just made a navigation drawer having some fragments. I want to put some music on one fragment using MediaPlayer so that when button is click it play music but when i add raw resource file androidstudio do red and shows error cannot resolve method.Can anyone help me how to import media player in Menu1 fragment.

```
public class Menu1 extends Fragment  {
MediaPlayer mp;



@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu1, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    getActivity().setTitle("Happy B'day Dear");
    mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.hpbday);
    Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnplay);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Try this  mp=MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(),R.raw.hpbday);

Comment: but it shows findViewById red color ?

Comment: view.findViewById().....I think you are in fragment

Comment: Thanku so much your both comments work